# How to make a dropdown menu in react-native using core components without using third part libraries

Tags: javascript, react-native, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, icons

How to make a dropdown menu, modal in react-native without using third-party libraries? here is how you can do it.  Is there any better way you can come up with please reply with your answers.

feel free to give a like and thumbs up to get more.

[Android Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSjG3.png) - Screenshot

[Web Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2xXA.png) - Screenshot

[iOs Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42k22.png) - Screenshot

[Click Me!!! to try this code on Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@deepakkaligotla/react-native-dropdown-modal)

This code doesn't have any third-party library except icons, I love icons!!! :D ;) <3

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, Dimensions, Modal, 
TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

export default class SignUp extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        genders: ['Male', 'Female', 'Others'],
        genderModal: false,
        selectedGender: "Select Gender",
        genderDropdownTop: 0,
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "black", marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10, width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 30, height: 600 }}>
                {/* Selecting person dropdown */}
                <View>
                    <Modal visible={this.state.genderModal}
                        transparent
                        animationType="slide"
                        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ genderModal: false })}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={{ width: '100%', height: '80%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#000000', width: 130, shadowRadius: 4, shadowOffset: { height: 4, width: 0 }, shadowOpacity: 0.5, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, top: this.state.genderDropdownTop }}>
                                <FlatList
                                    data={this.state.genders}
                                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingVertical: 10, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1 }} onPress={() => {
                                            this.setState({ genderModal: false })
                                            this.setState({ selectedGender: item })
                                        }}>
                                            <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}> {item} </Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    )}
                                    keyExtractor={(index) => index.toString()}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </Modal>
                </View>
                < View style={{ flexDirection: 'row-reverse', borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, width: 150, marginTop: 10 }}>
                    <Pressable
                        onPress={() => this.setState({ genderModal: true })}>
                        <Icon size={30} color="white" name="circledown" />
                    </Pressable>
                    < Text style={{ color: 'white', marginRight: 10, fontSize: 20 }}> {this.state.selectedGender} </Text>
                </View>
            </View >
        </>
    );
}
}
```